# Can't install any OS after replacing hard drive

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, installation

I recently upgraded my computer's HDD from 320 GB to 500 GB. It's a Toshiba L650.

I tried to install Windows 7 on it but due to some file error I wasn't able to install it successfully. While installing Windows I made some partitions and later when the Windows 7 didn't install successfully I deleted the partitions by connecting that HDD to some other computer externally.

So, I tried installing Linux from a DVD now and at boot time – before the actual installer starts –, it shows:

> no bootable disks found, insert bootable disk and press enter.

I made sure to set the boot order to CD/DVD. I've also verified the HDD is running (the light is blinking) and that the disk size is supported by the system.

Comment: Is that disk size supported by the PC? How did you partition it?

Comment: You can do the partitioning before installing any OS...

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Only and one of the best way to create partitions when you install th OS. When you will prompt to select tje partition to install tje OS there is an option advanced in Windows 7. Select it and delete all partitions and recreate them and windows will automatically do te rest for you.

Comment: Now windows is not finding any primary partitions to install so the Os are not accepting the HDD. Just format the HDD at the installation time of Windows and recreate the partitions and you will be able to install the Os.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the partition, recreate it, then format it. Any file-based problems will be gone.

Both Windows and Linux can do all of that during the installation, you just have to select "advanced" options during the install to get to the disk partition/change options.

Answer (score 0):

## Not an answer but tidbits of helpful info.

#### 1 - Partitioning:

grab yourself a copy of gparted > http://gparted.sourceforge.net/

#### 2 - Boot Sequence for Toshiba:

From the Toshiba Manual:
"To change the boot drive, follow the steps below.
1. Hold down F12 and boot the computer. 
When the TOSHIBA Leading
Innovation >>> screen appears, release the F12 key.
2. Use the up and down cursor keys to select the boot device you want
and press ENTER"

#### 3 - IDE/SETA Compatibility Mode for Toshiba:

The BIOS contains an option called SATA mode;
If it’s set to AHCI then you will need SATA drivers.
If the compatible mode has been chosen, then you will not need the SATA drivers. 
The HDD controller will work and appear in IDE mode.

#### 4 - Fixing the MBR in Windows 7:

http://www.tomshardware.com/news/win7-windows-7-mbr,10036.html
[also covers setting active partition]

#### 5 - Repair broken bootloader's:

http://www.supergrubdisk.org/